# Why does a lookahead in an optional 0-width capture group prevent the group from matching?

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider the following regex:

```
(^.)?
```

This matches a single character at the start of the string, if possible:

```
>> 'ab'.match(/(^.)?/)
Array [ "a", "a" ]
```

However, wrapping the `.` in a lookahead causes it to stop working:

```
>> 'ab'.match(/(^(?=.))?/)
Array [ "", undefined ]
```

The value of `undefined` indicates that the group didn't match, rather than having matched an empty string. But I don't understand how the lookahead prevents the group from matching. I would have expected to get a result of `["", ""]` here.

Even more curiously, this is only the case if the surrounding capture group has a width of 0. If we change the `^` anchor to something longer, it works correctly again:

```
>> 'ab'.match(/(a(?=.))?/)
Array [ "a", "a" ]
```

Removing the `?` that makes the group optional fixes the output as well:

```
>> 'ab'.match(/(^(?=.))/)
Array [ "", "" ]
```

Can someone explain why this happens? It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: The examples in the update are different. They work correctly.

Comment: @melpomene What? How is that output correct? What's the difference between the regex in the update and the one above? Can you elaborate?

Comment: The match isn't failing, since it's returning an array, not `null`, and `[0]` contains the full match. It's just the capture group that's undefined.

Comment: @Barmar I was trying to say that the group fails to match; I wasn't referring to the entire regex.

Comment: Regexes always match at the leftmost possible position. If all of a regex is optional (as in `(b(?=c))?`), it always matches at offset 0. `'abcd'.match(/(b(?=c))?/)` can't match `b` with `a`, so the capture group fails, but the whole regex still succeeds at position 0.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for explaining; you're absolutely right. \*facepalm\* I guess I'll edit it out again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn’t need to involve lookaheads. Any group that ends up with an empty match and is itself optional won’t match.

```
> /()/.exec('foo')
['', '']

> /()?/.exec('foo')
['', undefined]
```

It’s pretty weird, yep.

```
> /(.*?)/.exec('foo')
['', '']

> /(.*?)?/.exec('foo')
['f', 'f']
```

There’s [a V8 test case](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/e2ab7dae4789689e236f864d63c8763ceed21645/test/webkit/fast/regex/repeat-match-waldemar-expected.txt#L45) that suggests the behaviour is expected. [This part of the spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-repeatmatcher-abstract-operation)

> If min is zero and y's endIndex is equal to x's endIndex, return failure.

seems relevant but is really hard to understand. If it’s actually causing the behaviour here (while trying to avoid having a group match consecutive empty strings?), I’d consider it a spec bug. Other languages don’t behave the same. (Not that they have to, but it’s another strike.)

Actually, [the behaviour has been described before](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=369778#c12) with a comment about being explained in the spec, but it’s really not *explained* at all. (There’s an `(a*)*` note with no corresponding output, plus the aforequoted step which is offered without justification except in some other notes about the problem of repeating empty matches which, again, everyone else seems to have solved in the more intuitive way.)

#### Python

```py
>>> re.match(r'(.*?)?', 'foo').group(0, 1)
('', '')
```

#### .NET

```vb
> Dim m = Regex.Match("foo", "(.*?)?")
> m.Success
True
> m.Length
0
```

#### Ruby

```rb
> 'foo' =~ /(.*?)?/
0
> $1
""
```

#### Perl

```perl
> 'foo' =~ /(.*?)?/
('')
```

Comment: It's not a bug. It's matching the empty string at the beginning, see my answer.

Comment: @Barmar `undefined` is not an empty string.

Comment: I don't understand your test case link. None of the cases expect `[undefined]`. How is it relevant?

Comment: @melpomene: The highlighted line would logically seem to match `[""]`, and it does so in other languages.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: You probably shouldn’t accept this yet. It’s kind of a research direction.

Comment: Oh, wow. Yeah, I also think `/(?:a*?)?/.exec("a")` should be `""`.

Comment: Has anyone reported this as a bug in Chrome or Firefox yet?

Comment: @melpomene: It’s unclear to me how related https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=576822 is

Comment: @mel I still don't get it. Barmar said that there are multiple matches, the single match (not with `g`) just happen to return the match which the () doesn't match.

Comment: @user202729: `/g` won’t find a match with an empty matched group. (In other words, it makes no difference. And I should hope it wouldn’t…)

Comment: I suspect the motivation behind that spec rule involves stopping zero-width matches inside `*` or `+` quantifiers from going on forever.

Comment: (It's not the best way to deal with zero-width matches inside quantifiers, but at this point, backward compatibility is a big deal.)

Comment: I wasn't fully aware of the consequences of this behavior until I saw that `(.*?)?` example. That's quite a gotcha.

Comment: I see `(a*?)?` matches `a` but `(a*?)+?` matches a zero-length position (not JS only), even though former means `{0,1}` (greedy) latter means `{1,}` (lazy)

Comment: So `(a??)?` is expected to end up with an empty match and returns nothing but it returns `a` as a match (JS only).